# replyTo bug in GmailApp.sendEmail()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google App Script to create and send PDF upon getting a form submit. The problem is the replyTo address that you specify in GmailApp.sendEmail(). If I look at email header in the mail that is received from this script, the replyTo is garbage.

The "replyto" looks like this (new numbers for every email):

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@6022f130

Spontaneous, even though I somehow may use some of this functions wrong, it should either return an error, or not setting the replyTo header at all?

```
function onFormSubmit(e) 
{
      [...]
      var replyTo = e.namedValues["E-postadress"]; 

      GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {
        replyTo: replyTo,
        name: "Example",
        from: "info@example.com”,
        attachments: [pdf.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
      });
}
```

Any suggestions of anything that I am doing wrong? Or is it clearly a bug of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
var replyTo = e.namedValues["E-postadress"][0];
```

assuming that the form response is just an email, this should be ok.